# ¿Cómo puedo implementar la función de Widgets Tree de Flutter en VIM?

Tags: flutter, plugin, vim

Quiero obtener la función de tagbar de los Widgets de Flutter en Vim. Tal como muestra este repositorio.

https://github.com/theniceboy/coc-flutter-tools

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para ser más específico, en el GIF del respositorio o en la imagen, hay una barra en la derecha que muestra los Widgets de forma de índice para acceder a ellos fácilmente. Pero no logro conseguir mostrarlo o que me aparezca en VIM.

Este es mi configuración de CocConfig:

```
{
  "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": [
    "css",
    "markdown",
    "javascript",
    "graphql",
    "html",
    "yaml",
    "json",
    "python",
    "dart"
  ],
  // python config
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  // dart config
  "flutter.UIPath": true,
  "flutter.enabled": true,
  "flutter.provider.enableSnippet": true,
  "flutter.outlineWidth": 30,
  "flutter.outlineIconPadding": 0,
  "snippets.ultisnips.directories": [
    "UltiSnips",
    "~/.config/nvim/utils/snips"
  ]
}
```

Tengo también instalado los plugins de
`dart-vim-plugin` , pero no se si me falta algún plugin.
Si alguien ha podido ejecutarlo, estaría agradecido con la ayuda.

He instalado y seguido todos los pasos, pero no me muestra nada

Comment: ¿Estas usando NeoVim o un Vim tradicional?

Comment: Estoy usando NeoVim y Manjaro Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba directamente con Coc.

```
:CocCommand flutter.toggleOutline
```

luego agregar a tu .vimrc

```
nnoremap <leader>fo :CocCommand flutter.toggleOutline<cr>
```